# jsocks library for proxy

Tags: java, sockets, proxy, serversocket, socks

it's been a 2 days i find "jSocks" library.

i tried so may to findout how i can code with this library.

i must say that documentation is very poor.

i **don't** want you to code for me, i just want a **simple workflow**.

**here is my scenario:**

1) i want to write 2 app, one for client and one for server.**(it's simple client server proxy)**

2) client app will listen to specific port on localhost (127.0.0.1) for incoming connection (for example browser request).

3) client app accept incoming connection from browser and create a socks socket between her and browser for send and recieve data.

4) client app create a socks socket between her and server app (server app hosted on web and listening to a port for incoming connection).

5) server app accept incoming connection and create a socks socket for Communicate.

6) server app recieve data ( may be browser request ), process it and connect to a remote web site(on internet).

7) server app recive data from web and send it to client app.

8) client app send the recived data to browser.

i create this app with java standard "Socket" & "ServerSocket" for http request without problem, now i want to write this program with socks socket for all request.

i tried every thing with jsocks without any success.

i need a **workflow** on how to work with **jsocks** for creating this app.

tnx.

---

@BGR

acording to your mentioned file (SOCKS.java) the simple line like below must work :

`ServerAuthenticator auth = new ServerAuthenticatorNone();`

`ProxyServer pServer = new ProxyServer(auth);`

`pServer.setLog(System.out);`

`pServer.start(50352);`

when i execute this, the log is : Starting SOCKS Proxy on:0.0.0.0:50352 (if i pass 127.0.0.1 as address to `start()` method, log is "Starting SOCKS Proxy on:127.0.0.1:50352 but the result is the same)

but when i redirect my browser request to this port nothing happens.

acually i'am not sure how the `start(port)` method works, because it's void.

when i use `ServerSocket`, `accept()` method it return me a Socket for communication.

but when i use `start(port)` nothing will return

Comment: Just curious: If you have it working fine, why use jSocks?

Comment: Could you straighten out your terminology. Clients don't listen. Servers listen. Clients connect.

Comment: @Fildor

i want to use socks (because it preform in lower layer (i think in tcp layer) than normal socket), and only implementation of socks socket in java that i found is jsocks, do you know any other implementation?

Comment: @EJP
in my case both client and server are listening( i think my client is a server too)
as i said, client listen to local request(from browser) and connect to server and send browser request.
the server are listening to incoming connection from client, then connect to it, then connect to another web site (that browser rquest it).
it's a simple client server proxy like freegate, yourfreedom or other proxy prog

Comment: Do you have a link to the library? Google gives me several hits that don't really seem to be what you are talking about.

Comment: @Fildor: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsocks/
there is also github and googlecode mirror for this

Comment: Ah now I see. Did you have a look at the SOCKS Protocol? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOCKS

Comment: @Fildor:
 yes i was read it, i was read the socks RFC (that long text file),
this is not my problem, i understand socks, the problem is i can not use this library

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? In the docu, I can see Proxy classes and I can see ProxyServer classes ... But it really lacks some examples to get started. I'm afraid I'm not much of a help.

Comment: @Fildor: i tried ProxyServer class before, it has a start(port) for listening to the port and accept connection, when i call this method it stuck and noting happen. i set my browser to send her request through the port

Comment: You mean it blocked? I don't know if you have to configure it somehow before starting. And if `start` blocks, I'd try to put it in a thread ...

Comment: @Fildor: yes, it blocked for incoming connection, please see my edited question in response to BGR

Comment: Hold on. You do not "redirect your browser to the socks port". This is transparently handled by your browser when you tell it to use a Socks proxy. Try to `telnet localhost 50352` to see if the sock server port is opened then configure the proxy on your browser (btw 127.0.0.1 != 0.0.0.0 - the latter opens the port on ALL local addresses)

Comment: @BGR:
ops, the connection was made and log say : Accepted from:127.0.0.1:57673 ,

but here is still 2 problem: 1)why the browser can not make connection?

2) as i said 'start()' method is void, so how i can get my socket to get input and output stream?

Comment: I believe you misunderstand how a Socks proxy works. The Socks proxy creates a tunnel to which your browser or Java Socket first connects and then through which the rest of the actual connection is handled. Please re-read the Wikipedia entry on the SOCKS proxy

Comment: @BGR: OK, i'm in confusing state now, was i misunderstand whole process at all?  according to this i don't need to handle any socket instance and any input output stream,  instead, for client, i must create an Proxy instance to connect server, then Create a ProxyServer instance to listen and connect to browser. then i must pass Proxy instance to ProxyServer instance (this mean sending browser request to server transparentlly).  for server i must create a ProxyServer instance to listen and connect to client.  so the rest of communication automatically done.  am i right?

Comment: If your client listens and connects, it isn't a client, it is a proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I full understand your request (a socks server is meant for proxying; it is constantly listening on a single port and forwards requests) but looking at [this java file](https://github.com/ravn/jsocks/blob/master/src/com/runjva/sourceforge/jsocks/main/SOCKS.java) it seems reasonable easy to create a Socks proxy server using jsocks.

Once you proxy server is running, you create a java socket on your client using [this constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.Proxy%29) where you specify the location of your socks proxy server. You then `connect` to your remote server `SocketAddress` and

... that should be it.

You seem to have lot of redirections going on. Maybe you should chart a diagram of your flows and see where you need a Socks proxy server and why.

Comment: please see the edited question. i can't format the comment so i answer you there.